# Limit of Exponential Integral Function

Tags: calculus, limits

I want to ask how to prove whether the following limit is corrent
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \left[ {x{e^x}{E_1}( x )} \right] = 0,
$$
with
$\displaystyle {E_1}( x ) = \int_x^\infty  \frac{e^{ - t}}{t}dt$. I try to run it by Matlab and it seems to be true.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substitute $t=x+s$ in the integral. As a result,
$$ xe^xE_1(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{x}{x+s}e^{-s}\,ds.$$
Now the integrand goes to $1$ as $x\to\infty$, so a much more likely value of the limit is $$\int_0^\infty e^{-s}\,ds=1.$$

Comment: Sorry! I still don't get it.

Comment: I added some detail. I haven't finished the proof, though. (In part because I am heading for bed, and because I wonder if this is home work?)

Comment: Let $t = x+s$ in the integral, the result should be $$xe^xE_1(x)=\int_x^\infty \frac{x}{x+s}e^{-s}\,ds.$$

Comment: No, the lower limit $t=x$ corresponds to $s=0$, surely?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following results:
$$
{e^x}{E_1}\left( x \right) \le \ln \left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right)
$$
and
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} {\left( {1 + \frac{1}{x}} \right)^x} = 1
$$
to arrive at the limit.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\log\left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right) < e^x E_1(x) < \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right),\,x>0
\end{align}
Multiply everywhere by $x$ and apply the Phillycheesesteak theorem.

Comment: While I appreciate your attempt at humour, Phillycheesesteak reminds me more of [this theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ham_sandwich_theorem) which is different, and should not be confused with, [this theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).